# How to preserve specific arguments when currying?

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I have a function foo x y z -> xyz 
Now usually I could curry by giving foo x y then linking it to another arguement. My question is what if I didn't want to change the order of the arguments, but I wanted to hold x and z constant. How would I "curry" that to a y argument.
Perhaps context might help understand: Suppose I wanted to apply something to a list with the for_all function. My predicate p has the list as first argument, how would I do this? 
(Note though a specific example is appreciated, I'm hoping for also more of a general and elegant(-ish?) approach that I could use again.
Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to use named arguments, in which case you can select which argument you wish to supply by name: `let foo ~x ~y ~z = ...`, and then `foo ~y:value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to look at currying is a shortcut for

```
fun z -> f x y z
```

Therefore, you can just manually declare the same thing for what you want

```
fun y -> f x y z
```

Answer (score 0):

Currying only works for the arguments in the order they are defined. It's therefore important to specify arguments in the order you most likely want to curry them.

So in `f x y z` you can't use currying to make x and z constant. But you can simply define a new function:

```
let f_y y = f 1 y 5
```

or as a factory:

```
let with_constant_x_z f x z = fun y -> f x y z
```